# Custom cursor in XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xna-4.0

So I've been following this answer:
[Adding a custom cursor in XNA/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371657/adding-a-custom-cursor-in-xna-c)

... to get a custom mouse cursor working on XNA.

I've done everything like the solution, get no error, but still get no custom cursor (it still shows the windows default one).

I'm unsure on what to do really...

I created the getCursorPos method at the bottom of my Game1.cs file, included the following declarations at the begining of Game1 class:

```
private MouseState mouseState;
private int cursorX;
private int cursorY;
```

The code in LoadContent was giving me an error:

```
cursorTex = content.Load<Texture2D>("cursor.png");
```

so I replaced it with:

```
cursorTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>("cursor");
```

("cursor" is a png)

What am I doing wrong?... Like I said, no error :(

Comment: have you added the cursor.png to your project? also, this is flagged windows phone - you have no mouse on your phone.

Comment: Nowhere in that answer is the mouse state updated, you probably need to do this.

Comment: @UrbanEsc: on WP7 the `Mouse` class is emulated from the touch inputs.

Comment: @Joao: You need to add your `png` file to your XNA Content Project. That will build the `png` file into an `xnb` file, which is what `Content.Load` actually loads.

Comment: @Andrew Russell yeah sure, but you wont actually see the mouse, since your finger is on it. And you tend to tap on stuff, not move a mouse around to point at things. It just does not make sense to me in a way.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you need to update the mouse's position, using `mouseState = Mouse.GetState();` (put it in your game's update method, before you update the `cursorPos` variable).