# XNA Mouse position is off

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm working on a miniature golf game in XNA, I originally had everything in Game.cs (main), but I now want it to be more object-oriented, so I made separate class for most of my stuff.

When I had everything in Game.cs, it was working fine, now it doesn't.

What is happening is this:

When my cursor is at the top left corner of the game window, it's like X=200, Y=50.
It's supposed to be X=0, Y=0.
Even when I look for the 0, 0 position, it's way outside the game window.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

How is that possible? Your cursor position *is* the mouse position. Simply draw the cursor there.

Unless you are talking about the Windows cursor. In that case, yes, the input data in XNA will not match the Windows cursor movement. They probably apply some modifiers for acceleration, etc. You have to interprete the input data yourself. In other words, **draw your own cursor.**

Comment: Let me try to explain my problem more clear. When I move my mouse to the top left corner of the game window, it is not 0, 0; it is a completely different number and I don't know why.
  
Here are two pictures: 
http://i.imgur.com/KOp4kDW.png (my mouse is in top left corner of game)
http://i.imgur.com/FdRXx9g.png (my mouse is at (0, 0) which is far outside the game)

Here is the code to get the mouse position:
'code'MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
            
            xM = mouseState.X;
            yM = mouseState.Y;'code'

Comment: Like I said. This is the *standard Windows cursor*. It **will** be off. You have to hide the Windows cursor and [draw a custom one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371657/adding-a-custom-cursor-in-xna-c).