# C# XNA: Change the Mouse Pointer to a Cursor Hand

Tags: c#, xna

I need to change the cursor in XNA from an Arrow pointer to the Hand that appears when you hover over a URL link. I did a google search and had no luck in finding any suitable code. I am using the XNA Mouse class for the project.

Can this be done easily?

I appreciate any help that can be given

Comment: I am not familiar with XNA but this might work for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371657/adding-a-custom-cursor-in-xna-c

Comment: Thank you Lior that was exactly what I needed :)